# How Keyboard's caps lock key on for the first letter for text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am developing a cordova application. For input text, I want to enable keyboard's caps lock key  for the first letter. Previously I used text-form:capitalise but user can't change again first letter to lower case if he want first letter lower case(capitalise property not make caps lock key enable on key board). 
Simply I want caps-lock key on while typing first letter and if user disable it, then he can type first letter as lower case.

Any css ,html, jquery, javascript solutions guys? I have number of text fields in my app an I wish the solution is applicable for all input type="text".

Sample text field I entered below:

```
<input id="candidate_first_name" placeholder="Candidate First Name*" 
                                            type="text" class="ui-input-shadow-text">
```

Comment: I think you mean the `Shift` key. Mobile apps sometimes have input fields where the Shift key is enabled when the field just _became_ empty or got _focused while_ empty. This is most commonly seen on name fields. Is this what you mean?

Comment: That would not be good UI design. Ultimately, you have to allow users to enter what they want, especially if all lower-case is acceptable. If it is important, then I would encourage initial caps with a placeholder message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn on capslock or the shift key directly.

You can capture the keypress event and, just afterward, if the field has one character, make it upper case. The problem then is avoiding messing up the user's cursor location. On most modern browsers, you can do that by setting the caret position after updating the field. If the user doesn't want it to be capped, they'll have to go back and edit, which isn't ideal.

I wouldn't do this in a general web page (if at all), too many browsers out there to test with to avoid issues that make users unhappy, but if you have a more limited scenario and can test adequately with your target browsers, it may be feasible.

Here's an example that works on current Chrome, Firefox, IE, and iOS Safari:

```js
$("#testing").on("keypress", function(e) {
  // Only do it if the field is blank before the keypress
  // (the event occurs before the character is added to
  // the field)
  if (this.value.length === 0) {
    setTimeout(maybeCap.bind(this), 0);
  }
});

function maybeCap() {
  // Only do it if the field now has a single character
  if (this.value.length == 1) {
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    setCaretPosition(this, 1);
  }
}

function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
  if (elem) {
    if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.move('character', caretPos);
      range.select();
    } else {
      if (elem.selectionStart) {
        elem.focus();
        elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
      } else
        elem.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="testing">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or as a jQuery plugin:

```js
$.fn.capFirst = function() {
  this.on("keypress", keypressHandler);
  
  function keypressHandler(e) {
    // Only do it if the field is blank before the keypress
    // (the event occurs before the character is added to
    // the field)
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
      setTimeout(maybeCap.bind(this), 0);
    }
  }
  
  function maybeCap() {
    // Only do it if the field now has a single character
    if (this.value.length == 1) {
      this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
      setCaretPosition(this, 1);
    }
  }

  function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
    if (elem) {
      if (elem.createTextRange) {
        var range = elem.createTextRange();
        range.move('character', caretPos);
        range.select();
      } else {
        if (elem.selectionStart) {
          elem.focus();
          elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
        } else
          elem.focus();
      }
    }
  }
};

$("input[type=text]").capFirst();
```

```html
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for answers.First letter capitalisation already working  with css property 'text-form:capitalise' but the problem is it Forcefully make first letter as Caps lock but i user want to make the first letter small what i do?

Comment: thank you guys i actually looking for the solution ,when user click input text the caps lock key on and after first character it should turned of.

Comment: @LejinK.R: As I said above, they can do that, but they have to go back and change it. E.g., if I wanted to type `foo` in the boxes above, I'd type `foo`, which would get changed to `Foo`, then go back and replace the `F` with an `f`. Not ideal, but you can't do it via the keyboard's capslock or shift keys.

Comment: Am working with cordova mobile app for android and ios.

Comment: In your code i think when length is 1 then capitalise right?